# Как сделать, чтобы закрашивались предыдущие звёзды рейтинга, идущие перед чекнутой?

Tags: html, css

С ховером работает, а с :checked не могу сделать. Не понимаю, что не так.

```css
.form__rating-input {
  display: none;
}

.form__rating {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.form__rating-input:checked+.form__star-image,
.form__rating-input:checked~.form__rating-label .form__star-image,
.form__rating-input:focus+.form__star-image,
.form__rating-label:hover .form__star-image,
.form__rating-label:hover~.form__rating-label .form__star-image {
  fill: #F2994A;
  stroke: #F2994A;
}

.form__star-image {
  stroke: #666876;
  fill: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="form__rating">
  <label for="1-stars" class="form__rating-label mb-0" title="3">
          <input class="form__rating-input" name="rating" value=3 id="3-stars" type="radio">
          <svg class="form__star-image" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M5.0031 23.997C4.89863 23.9898 4.79666 23.9603 4.70344 23.9104C4.61021 23.8605 4.5277 23.7912 4.46094 23.7068C4.39419 23.6223 4.3446 23.5245 4.31522 23.4193C4.28583 23.3141 4.27727 23.2038 4.29005 23.095L5.22594 15.4902L0.204812 9.90719C0.111778 9.802 0.0472504 9.67272 0.0178906 9.5327C-0.0114691 9.39267 -0.00459667 9.24698 0.0377982 9.11066C0.080193 8.97435 0.156574 8.85236 0.259055 8.75727C0.361536 8.66218 0.486403 8.59745 0.620764 8.56976L7.81078 7.15455L11.3167 0.420694C11.3828 0.29341 11.4804 0.187148 11.5994 0.113107C11.7183 0.039066 11.8542 0 11.9926 0C12.131 0 12.2668 0.039066 12.3858 0.113107C12.5047 0.187148 12.6024 0.29341 12.6685 0.420694L16.1744 7.15455L23.3792 8.56976C23.5136 8.59745 23.6385 8.66218 23.7409 8.75727C23.8434 8.85236 23.9198 8.97435 23.9622 9.11066C24.0046 9.24698 24.0115 9.39267 23.9821 9.5327C23.9527 9.67272 23.8882 9.802 23.7952 9.90719L18.7741 15.4902L19.71 23.095C19.7271 23.2388 19.7068 23.3848 19.6513 23.5176C19.5958 23.6504 19.507 23.765 19.3945 23.8494C19.2819 23.9338 19.1497 23.9848 19.0117 23.9971C18.8738 24.0094 18.7352 23.9825 18.6107 23.9192L12 20.6223L5.37449 23.9192C5.25882 23.9771 5.13116 24.0038 5.0031 23.997Z" />
          </svg>
        </label>
  <label for="2-stars" class="form__rating-label" title="2">
          <input class="form__rating-input" name="rating" value=2 id="2-stars" type="radio">
          <svg class="form__star-image" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M5.0031 23.997C4.89863 23.9898 4.79666 23.9603 4.70344 23.9104C4.61021 23.8605 4.5277 23.7912 4.46094 23.7068C4.39419 23.6223 4.3446 23.5245 4.31522 23.4193C4.28583 23.3141 4.27727 23.2038 4.29005 23.095L5.22594 15.4902L0.204812 9.90719C0.111778 9.802 0.0472504 9.67272 0.0178906 9.5327C-0.0114691 9.39267 -0.00459667 9.24698 0.0377982 9.11066C0.080193 8.97435 0.156574 8.85236 0.259055 8.75727C0.361536 8.66218 0.486403 8.59745 0.620764 8.56976L7.81078 7.15455L11.3167 0.420694C11.3828 0.29341 11.4804 0.187148 11.5994 0.113107C11.7183 0.039066 11.8542 0 11.9926 0C12.131 0 12.2668 0.039066 12.3858 0.113107C12.5047 0.187148 12.6024 0.29341 12.6685 0.420694L16.1744 7.15455L23.3792 8.56976C23.5136 8.59745 23.6385 8.66218 23.7409 8.75727C23.8434 8.85236 23.9198 8.97435 23.9622 9.11066C24.0046 9.24698 24.0115 9.39267 23.9821 9.5327C23.9527 9.67272 23.8882 9.802 23.7952 9.90719L18.7741 15.4902L19.71 23.095C19.7271 23.2388 19.7068 23.3848 19.6513 23.5176C19.5958 23.6504 19.507 23.765 19.3945 23.8494C19.2819 23.9338 19.1497 23.9848 19.0117 23.9971C18.8738 24.0094 18.7352 23.9825 18.6107 23.9192L12 20.6223L5.37449 23.9192C5.25882 23.9771 5.13116 24.0038 5.0031 23.997Z" />
          </svg>
        </label>
  <label for="3-stars" class="form__rating-label" title="1">
          <input class="form__rating-input" name="rating" value=1 id="1-stars" type="radio">
          <svg class="form__star-image" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M5.0031 23.997C4.89863 23.9898 4.79666 23.9603 4.70344 23.9104C4.61021 23.8605 4.5277 23.7912 4.46094 23.7068C4.39419 23.6223 4.3446 23.5245 4.31522 23.4193C4.28583 23.3141 4.27727 23.2038 4.29005 23.095L5.22594 15.4902L0.204812 9.90719C0.111778 9.802 0.0472504 9.67272 0.0178906 9.5327C-0.0114691 9.39267 -0.00459667 9.24698 0.0377982 9.11066C0.080193 8.97435 0.156574 8.85236 0.259055 8.75727C0.361536 8.66218 0.486403 8.59745 0.620764 8.56976L7.81078 7.15455L11.3167 0.420694C11.3828 0.29341 11.4804 0.187148 11.5994 0.113107C11.7183 0.039066 11.8542 0 11.9926 0C12.131 0 12.2668 0.039066 12.3858 0.113107C12.5047 0.187148 12.6024 0.29341 12.6685 0.420694L16.1744 7.15455L23.3792 8.56976C23.5136 8.59745 23.6385 8.66218 23.7409 8.75727C23.8434 8.85236 23.9198 8.97435 23.9622 9.11066C24.0046 9.24698 24.0115 9.39267 23.9821 9.5327C23.9527 9.67272 23.8882 9.802 23.7952 9.90719L18.7741 15.4902L19.71 23.095C19.7271 23.2388 19.7068 23.3848 19.6513 23.5176C19.5958 23.6504 19.507 23.765 19.3945 23.8494C19.2819 23.9338 19.1497 23.9848 19.0117 23.9971C18.8738 24.0094 18.7352 23.9825 18.6107 23.9192L12 20.6223L5.37449 23.9192C5.25882 23.9771 5.13116 24.0038 5.0031 23.997Z" />
          </svg>
        </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Не так то, что у Вас input является дочерним элементом для label, а Вы через него пытаетесь менять состояние соседнего родителя:

`.form__rating-input:checked ~ .form__rating-label .form__star-image` - при Вашей нынешней разметке такая конструкция работать не будет. Нужно вынести инпуты на один уровень с лейблами и поменять местами id="3-stars" и id="1-stars" - тогда всё получится

```css
.form__rating-input {
  display: none;
}

.form__rating {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.form__rating-input:checked+.form__star-image,
.form__rating-input:checked~.form__rating-label .form__star-image,
.form__rating-input:focus+.form__star-image,
.form__rating-label:hover .form__star-image,
.form__rating-label:hover~.form__rating-label .form__star-image {
  fill: #F2994A;
  stroke: #F2994A;
}

.form__star-image {
  stroke: #666876;
  fill: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="form__rating">
<input class="form__rating-input" name="rating" value=3 id="1-stars" type="radio">

  <label for="1-stars" class="form__rating-label mb-0" title="3">
       
          <svg class="form__star-image" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M5.0031 23.997C4.89863 23.9898 4.79666 23.9603 4.70344 23.9104C4.61021 23.8605 4.5277 23.7912 4.46094 23.7068C4.39419 23.6223 4.3446 23.5245 4.31522 23.4193C4.28583 23.3141 4.27727 23.2038 4.29005 23.095L5.22594 15.4902L0.204812 9.90719C0.111778 9.802 0.0472504 9.67272 0.0178906 9.5327C-0.0114691 9.39267 -0.00459667 9.24698 0.0377982 9.11066C0.080193 8.97435 0.156574 8.85236 0.259055 8.75727C0.361536 8.66218 0.486403 8.59745 0.620764 8.56976L7.81078 7.15455L11.3167 0.420694C11.3828 0.29341 11.4804 0.187148 11.5994 0.113107C11.7183 0.039066 11.8542 0 11.9926 0C12.131 0 12.2668 0.039066 12.3858 0.113107C12.5047 0.187148 12.6024 0.29341 12.6685 0.420694L16.1744 7.15455L23.3792 8.56976C23.5136 8.59745 23.6385 8.66218 23.7409 8.75727C23.8434 8.85236 23.9198 8.97435 23.9622 9.11066C24.0046 9.24698 24.0115 9.39267 23.9821 9.5327C23.9527 9.67272 23.8882 9.802 23.7952 9.90719L18.7741 15.4902L19.71 23.095C19.7271 23.2388 19.7068 23.3848 19.6513 23.5176C19.5958 23.6504 19.507 23.765 19.3945 23.8494C19.2819 23.9338 19.1497 23.9848 19.0117 23.9971C18.8738 24.0094 18.7352 23.9825 18.6107 23.9192L12 20.6223L5.37449 23.9192C5.25882 23.9771 5.13116 24.0038 5.0031 23.997Z" />
          </svg>
        </label>
        
        <input class="form__rating-input" name="rating" value=2 id="2-stars" type="radio">
  <label for="2-stars" class="form__rating-label" title="2">
          
          <svg class="form__star-image" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M5.0031 23.997C4.89863 23.9898 4.79666 23.9603 4.70344 23.9104C4.61021 23.8605 4.5277 23.7912 4.46094 23.7068C4.39419 23.6223 4.3446 23.5245 4.31522 23.4193C4.28583 23.3141 4.27727 23.2038 4.29005 23.095L5.22594 15.4902L0.204812 9.90719C0.111778 9.802 0.0472504 9.67272 0.0178906 9.5327C-0.0114691 9.39267 -0.00459667 9.24698 0.0377982 9.11066C0.080193 8.97435 0.156574 8.85236 0.259055 8.75727C0.361536 8.66218 0.486403 8.59745 0.620764 8.56976L7.81078 7.15455L11.3167 0.420694C11.3828 0.29341 11.4804 0.187148 11.5994 0.113107C11.7183 0.039066 11.8542 0 11.9926 0C12.131 0 12.2668 0.039066 12.3858 0.113107C12.5047 0.187148 12.6024 0.29341 12.6685 0.420694L16.1744 7.15455L23.3792 8.56976C23.5136 8.59745 23.6385 8.66218 23.7409 8.75727C23.8434 8.85236 23.9198 8.97435 23.9622 9.11066C24.0046 9.24698 24.0115 9.39267 23.9821 9.5327C23.9527 9.67272 23.8882 9.802 23.7952 9.90719L18.7741 15.4902L19.71 23.095C19.7271 23.2388 19.7068 23.3848 19.6513 23.5176C19.5958 23.6504 19.507 23.765 19.3945 23.8494C19.2819 23.9338 19.1497 23.9848 19.0117 23.9971C18.8738 24.0094 18.7352 23.9825 18.6107 23.9192L12 20.6223L5.37449 23.9192C5.25882 23.9771 5.13116 24.0038 5.0031 23.997Z" />
          </svg>
        </label>
        <input class="form__rating-input" name="rating" value=1 id="3-stars" type="radio">
  <label for="3-stars" class="form__rating-label" title="1">
          
          <svg class="form__star-image" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M5.0031 23.997C4.89863 23.9898 4.79666 23.9603 4.70344 23.9104C4.61021 23.8605 4.5277 23.7912 4.46094 23.7068C4.39419 23.6223 4.3446 23.5245 4.31522 23.4193C4.28583 23.3141 4.27727 23.2038 4.29005 23.095L5.22594 15.4902L0.204812 9.90719C0.111778 9.802 0.0472504 9.67272 0.0178906 9.5327C-0.0114691 9.39267 -0.00459667 9.24698 0.0377982 9.11066C0.080193 8.97435 0.156574 8.85236 0.259055 8.75727C0.361536 8.66218 0.486403 8.59745 0.620764 8.56976L7.81078 7.15455L11.3167 0.420694C11.3828 0.29341 11.4804 0.187148 11.5994 0.113107C11.7183 0.039066 11.8542 0 11.9926 0C12.131 0 12.2668 0.039066 12.3858 0.113107C12.5047 0.187148 12.6024 0.29341 12.6685 0.420694L16.1744 7.15455L23.3792 8.56976C23.5136 8.59745 23.6385 8.66218 23.7409 8.75727C23.8434 8.85236 23.9198 8.97435 23.9622 9.11066C24.0046 9.24698 24.0115 9.39267 23.9821 9.5327C23.9527 9.67272 23.8882 9.802 23.7952 9.90719L18.7741 15.4902L19.71 23.095C19.7271 23.2388 19.7068 23.3848 19.6513 23.5176C19.5958 23.6504 19.507 23.765 19.3945 23.8494C19.2819 23.9338 19.1497 23.9848 19.0117 23.9971C18.8738 24.0094 18.7352 23.9825 18.6107 23.9192L12 20.6223L5.37449 23.9192C5.25882 23.9771 5.13116 24.0038 5.0031 23.997Z" />
          </svg>
        </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, но мне надо, чтобы input был внутри label. Т.к. отрисовка рейтинга идёт в цикле *ngFor(angular). Цикл хочет работодатель. Поэтому инпукт отправила внутрь лейбла

Comment: @Anastasiya Voitulevich, тогда готовы JS использовать?

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо, получилось сделать. Т.к. инпут внутри лейбла для того, чтобы отрисовка была на angular, то и решение с выделением чекнутых звёзд оттуда же. Оставлю, вдруг тоже кому-то понадобится)

```js
export class SuccessSubmittedComponent implements OnInit {
  rate: number;
  stars: object[] = [
    {
      star: 5,
      title: `perfect`
    },
    {
      star: 4,
      title: `good`
    },
    {
      star: 3,
      title: `not bad`
    },
    {
      star: 2,
      title: `badly`
    },
    {
      star: 1,
      title: `terrible`
    }
  ];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

```css
.form__rating-label {
    &:not(:first-child) {
        margin-right: 16px;
    }    
}

.form__rating-label:hover .form__star-image,
.form__rating-label:hover ~ .form__rating-label .form__star-image {
    path {
        fill: #F2994A;
        stroke: #F2994A;
    }
}

.form__rating-checked .form__star-image path {
    fill: #F2994A;
    stroke: #F2994A;
}

.form__star-image path {
    stroke:  $color-secondary;
    fill: transparent;
}
```

```html
<label *ngFor="let star of stars; let idx = index" [class.form__rating-checked]="rate<=idx" (click)="rate=idx" 
        for="{{star.star}}-stars" class="form__rating-label form__rating-checked mb-0" title="{{star.title}}">
          <input class="form__rating-input" name="rating" value={{star.star}} id="{{star.star}}-stars" type="radio">
          <svg class="form__star-image" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M5.0031 23.997C4.89863 23.9898 4.79666 23.9603 4.70344 23.9104C4.61021 23.8605 4.5277 23.7912 4.46094 23.7068C4.39419 23.6223 4.3446 23.5245 4.31522 23.4193C4.28583 23.3141 4.27727 23.2038 4.29005 23.095L5.22594 15.4902L0.204812 9.90719C0.111778 9.802 0.0472504 9.67272 0.0178906 9.5327C-0.0114691 9.39267 -0.00459667 9.24698 0.0377982 9.11066C0.080193 8.97435 0.156574 8.85236 0.259055 8.75727C0.361536 8.66218 0.486403 8.59745 0.620764 8.56976L7.81078 7.15455L11.3167 0.420694C11.3828 0.29341 11.4804 0.187148 11.5994 0.113107C11.7183 0.039066 11.8542 0 11.9926 0C12.131 0 12.2668 0.039066 12.3858 0.113107C12.5047 0.187148 12.6024 0.29341 12.6685 0.420694L16.1744 7.15455L23.3792 8.56976C23.5136 8.59745 23.6385 8.66218 23.7409 8.75727C23.8434 8.85236 23.9198 8.97435 23.9622 9.11066C24.0046 9.24698 24.0115 9.39267 23.9821 9.5327C23.9527 9.67272 23.8882 9.802 23.7952 9.90719L18.7741 15.4902L19.71 23.095C19.7271 23.2388 19.7068 23.3848 19.6513 23.5176C19.5958 23.6504 19.507 23.765 19.3945 23.8494C19.2819 23.9338 19.1497 23.9848 19.0117 23.9971C18.8738 24.0094 18.7352 23.9825 18.6107 23.9192L12 20.6223L5.37449 23.9192C5.25882 23.9771 5.13116 24.0038 5.0031 23.997Z" />
          </svg>
        </label>
```